# Node.js on Azure Worker Role w/ SSL results in ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, azure

I have a WorkerRole configured to start node.exe via the Runtime/EntryPoint/ProgramEntryPoint element in the csdef and have a HttpsIn EndPoint configured for https on port 443 w/ a valid certificate.  I'm also setting the PORT environment variable in Runtime/Environment which is used by node to listen on for incoming requests.

When I start the service (either in local dev fabric or in Azure) and try to hit the service I get the following error:

```
SSL connection error
Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client authentication certificate that you don't have.
Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.
```

I have verified that node.exe is indeed started when the service starts, and if I look up the local port in the Compute Emulator, usually something like:

```
http://localhost:444
```

I am able to successfully hit node directly with that using my browser.  I am also able to hit node through Azure when SSL is not configured.

What am I missing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was using the http module instead of the https module when starting the web server in Node.  Works once I started the https server using the ssl certificate.

I was following a guide for SSL w/ Node in a WebRole, which requires a different set up than SSL w/ Node in WorkerRole.